# getting error on DigitalOcean, djangorestframework -> OSError: Input/output error

Tags: django-rest-framework, digital-ocean

Its a postman response from djangorestapi on digitalocean droplet. I don't know why its calling colorama package?
Please help if someone know.

Thanks in advance.

my code in file:

```
            data = response.json()
            if "status" in data:
                return JsonResponse({"status":data['code'],"msg":data['message']},safe=False)
            elif "status" in data['orders'][0] == "error":
                return JsonResponse({"status":500,"msg":data['message']},safe=False)
            else:    
                return JsonResponse({"status":200,"msg":data},safe=False)
```

**OUTPUT ON POSTMAN**

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://165.232.188.116:7000/new_order/

Django Version: 4.0.2
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'cdx']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/drf/cdx/views.py", line 100, in new_order
    return prime_new_order(request,dcx_key,dcx_sec,data)
  File "/root/drf/cdx/dcx_fetching/order/new_order.py", line 45, in prime_new_order
    if "status" in data:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 196, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.flush()

Exception Type: OSError at /new_order/
Exception Value: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:
[Errno 5] Input/output error
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py, line 196, in write_plain_text
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3

Its calling colorama, IDK why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its a print statement error generated by digital ocean kernel while executing code.**

Gunicorn have error log journal. You will find it there.